# How to search entire SQLite database for a string using only shell?

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell, scripting

Then I want to know the table and column string appears.

I can write a small shell script to do that, but I need guidelines.
Then I'll use it like this:

```
dbSearchString.sh "text to search for" database.db
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this shell script into a file named `dbSearchString.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

searchFor="$1"
db="$2"

sqlite3 "$db" .tables | while read table; do
    output=`sqlite3 -line "$db" "select * from $table" | grep "$searchFor"`
    if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Found in ${table}:"
        echo "$output"
    fi
done
```

Then use it like this in the command line:

```
dbSearchString.sh "text to search for" database.db
```

Output will be like:

```
Found in TABLE1:
          Z_PK = text to search for
     ZENTITYPK = text to search for
          Z_PK = text to search for

Found in TABLE2:
     ZENTITYPK = text to search for
          Z_PK = text to search for
```

Tested on macOS and Linux.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` can run POSIX shell where `[[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]` will fail as it is a Bashism. Do not test the value of `$?` but test the command and don't use decades deprecated backticks: `if output=$(sqlite3 -line "$db" "select * from $table" | grep "$searchFor"); then`. User `read -r` to prevent backslashes processing. And finally, running `grep` on an SQL dump may be a simpler solution.

Comment: Léa thanks for the comments, I found them very relevant.